# Determine all indexes of an element appearing more than once in an array using c#

Tags: c#, string

Calling **`Array.indexOf(input Array,"A")`** gives the index of "A" in input Array.But how to get all the index of "A" in the array if "A" occurs more than once in the input Array using a similar function.

Comment: (I knew I'd seen a very similar question recently. Found it now.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int[] indexes = input.Select((item, index) => new { item, index })
                     .Where(x => x.item == "A")
                     .Select(x => x.index)
                     .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following method from `Array` class

```
public static int FindIndex<T>(
    T[] array,
    int startIndex,
    Predicate<T> match)
```

It searches the array starting at startIndex and ending at the last element.

However, it should be used in a loop and in every next iteration the `startIndex` will be assigned a value `= previousIndexFound + 1`. Ofcourse, if that's less than the length of array.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an extension method for the `Array` class like this:

```
public static List<Int32> IndicesOf<T>(this T[] array, T value)
{
    var indices = new List<Int32>();

    Int32 startIndex = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        startIndex = Array.IndexOf<T>(array, value, startIndex);
        if (startIndex != -1)
        {
            indices.Add(startIndex);
            startIndex++;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return indices;
}
```

Usage example:

```
    var symbols = new Char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a' };
    var indices = symbols.IndicesOf('a');
    indices.ForEach(index => Console.WriteLine(index));
```